# Error in my JComboBox - does not choose the option selected

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

Here, is the Listener for the JComboBox for my Binary Search Tree program. From testing, it I've found out that when i choose the option in the combo box, the listener does not select the option that I choose. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
box.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getItem().equals("Inorder"))
                printInorder(nodeMain);
            else if(e.getItem().equals("Preorder"))
                printPreorder(nodeMain);
            else if(e.getItem().equals("Postorder"))
                printPostorder(nodeMain);
        }

        //Inorder
        void printInorder(Node node) 
        { 
           /* if (node == null) 
                return; 
            printInorder(node.left); 
            System.out.print(node.value + " "); 
            printInorder(node.right); */
            System.out.println("in selected");
        } 

        //Preorder
        void printPreorder(Node node) 
        { 
            /*if (node == null) 
                return; 
            System.out.print(node.value + " ");
            printPreorder(node.left); 
            printPreorder(node.right); */
            System.out.println("pre selected");
        } 

        //Postorder
         void printPostorder(Node node) 
            { 
                /*if (node == null) 
                    return; 
                printPostorder(node.left);
                printPostorder(node.right); 
                System.out.print(node.value + " "); */
             System.out.println("post selected");
            } 
    });

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).